# Where to place $PATH variable assertions in zsh?

Tags: macos, shell, zsh

I love `zsh`, but I am not sure where to place my `$PATH` and other variable assertions? I find that they are scattered between the files `.zshrc` `.zprofile` `.bashrc` `.bash_profile`, and sometimes doubled.

I realize that having anything inside the `bash` files doesn't make much sense seeing as I'm using `zsh`, but **where exactly should I be placing my `rvm`, `python`, `node` etc additions to my `$PATH`?**

Is there a specific file I should be using (i.e. `.zshenv` which does *not* currently exist in my installation), one of the ones I am currently using, or does it even matter?

Answer (score 265, accepted):

tl;dr version: use `~/.zshrc`

And [read the man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zshall) to understand the differences between:

> `~/.zshrc`, `~/.zshenv` and `~/.zprofile`.

---

### Regarding my comment

In my comment attached to the answer [kev gave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10576306/1084945), I said:

> This seems to be incorrect - /etc/profile isn't listed in any zsh documentation I can find.

This turns out to be partially incorrect: `/etc/profile` *may* be sourced by `zsh`. **However**, this only occurs if `zsh` is "invoked as `sh` or `ksh`"; in these compatibility modes:

> The usual zsh startup/shutdown scripts are not executed. Login shells source /etc/profile followed by $HOME/.profile. If the ENV environment variable is set on invocation, $ENV is sourced after the profile scripts. The value of ENV is subjected to parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion before being interpreted as a pathname. [[man zshall, "Compatibility"](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zshall)].

The [ArchWiki ZSH link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Zsh) says:

> At login, Zsh sources the following files in this order:
>   /etc/profile
>   This file is sourced by all Bourne-compatible shells upon login

This implys that `/etc/profile` is *always read* by `zsh` at login - I haven't got any experience with the Arch Linux project; the wiki may be correct for that distribution, but it is *not* generally correct. The information **is** incorrect compared to the zsh manual pages, and doesn't seem to apply to zsh on OS X (paths in `$PATH` set in `/etc/profile` do not make it to my zsh sessions).

---

### To address the question:

> where exactly should I be placing my rvm, python, node etc additions to my $PATH?

Generally, I would export my `$PATH` from `~/.zshrc`, but it's worth having a read of the [zshall](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zshall) man page, specifically the "STARTUP/SHUTDOWN FILES" section - `~/.zshrc` is read for *interactive* shells, which may or may not suit your needs - if you want the `$PATH` for every `zsh` shell invoked by you (both `interactive` and not, both `login` and not, etc), then `~/.zshenv` is a better option.

> Is there a specific file I should be using (i.e. .zshenv which does not currently exist in my installation), one of the ones I am currently using, or does it even matter?

There's a bunch of files read on startup (check the linked `man` pages), and there's a reason for that - each file has it's particular place (settings for every user, settings for user-specific, settings for login shells, settings for every shell, etc).
Don't worry about `~/.zshenv` not existing - if you need it, make it, and it will be read.

`.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` are **not** read by `zsh`, unless you explicitly source them from `~/.zshrc` or similar; the syntax between `bash` and `zsh` is *not* always compatible. Both `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` are designed for `bash` settings, not `zsh` settings.

Comment: Thanks for your more than thorough answer simont. Strange that you say `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` are not read by `zsh` as I presently have my `rvm` addition to `$PATH` in `.bashrc`, and my `python` addition in `.bash_profile`, and both are being added just fine. In any case, I'm going to move all my `$PATH` exports to `~/.zshrc` as all my other `zsh` configuration is housed there. I have to admit, I'm not too familiar with the different types of shells. From reading the links you posted, I'm guessing I use an interactive shell, but I'll read further to be sure... Thanks again!

Comment: I had problems with my zsh $PATH on Ubuntu 20.04, and it turns out that `~/.bashrc` is read by my `~/.profile` in my login shell. The check in `~/.profile` because reading `~/.bashrc` is `if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]`, which for some reason is set by my zsh, and so the condition is true.

Answer (score 54):

Here is the docs from the zsh man pages under STARTUP/SHUTDOWN FILES section.

```
   Commands  are  first  read from /etc/zshenv this cannot be overridden.
   Subsequent behaviour is modified by the RCS and GLOBAL_RCS options; the
   former  affects all startup files, while the second only affects global
   startup files (those shown here with an path starting with  a  /).   If
   one  of  the  options  is  unset  at  any point, any subsequent startup
   file(s) of the corresponding type will not be read.  It is also  possi-
   ble  for  a  file  in  $ZDOTDIR  to  re-enable GLOBAL_RCS. Both RCS and
   GLOBAL_RCS are set by default.

   Commands are then read from $ZDOTDIR/.zshenv.  If the shell is a  login
   shell,  commands  are  read from /etc/zprofile and then $ZDOTDIR/.zpro-
   file.  Then, if the  shell  is  interactive,  commands  are  read  from
   /etc/zshrc  and then $ZDOTDIR/.zshrc.  Finally, if the shell is a login
   shell, /etc/zlogin and $ZDOTDIR/.zlogin are read.
```

From this we can see the order files are read is:

```
/etc/zshenv    # Read for every shell
~/.zshenv      # Read for every shell except ones started with -f
/etc/zprofile  # Global config for login shells, read before zshrc
~/.zprofile    # User config for login shells
/etc/zshrc     # Global config for interactive shells
~/.zshrc       # User config for interactive shells
/etc/zlogin    # Global config for login shells, read after zshrc
~/.zlogin      # User config for login shells
~/.zlogout     # User config for login shells, read upon logout
/etc/zlogout   # Global config for login shells, read after user logout file
```

You can get more information [here](http://zshwiki.org/home/config/files).