# bash/zsh: which files get loaded at login?

Tags: bash, shell, path, zsh

Today when I checked my `$PATH` variable in Z shell (on OS X 10.8.3), I got the following result (I broke the lines for clarity):

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:
/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:
/usr/texbin:/usr/gcc-4.8.0/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin
```

The first and last lines are quite normal. `/usr/bin` etc. are somewhat default; and `/usr/gcc-4.8.0/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin` are what I manually loaded through `~/.zshrc`.

However, the middle line is peculiar. `X11` and `git` cannot be default, and they do not appear in `.zshrc` either. So I suppose there are files other than `.zshrc` that get loaded at login (I use login shells). What are these files then? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you have a look at the chapter `STARTUP/SHUTDOWN FILES` in the manpage of `zsh`?  Didn't it answer your questions?

Comment: For the first question mark, no at the time of posting; yes now. For the second question mark, yes. Thank you for the help!

Comment: [Here's an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10583324/1084945) that I think addresses your question.