# "source" command on mac

Tags: macos, shell, command

I have a `.bashrc` file on Mac OS in which I set some aliases. After I make it and I type `source .bashrc`, the aliases work perfectly. However if open another shell, my shortcut command will not be recognized and I need to do `source .bashrc` again. How can it make it once and for all?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/161249/bashrc-not-executed-when-opening-new-terminal.

Comment: I like the more cryptic `. .profile` or whatever file... I feel the cryptic . operator is very bash.

Comment: use mac os profile file ~/.zshrc https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574684/where-to-place-path-variable-assertions-in-zsh

Answer (score 10):

Terminal and iTerm 2 open new shells as login shells by default. When Bash is opened as a login shell, it reads `~/.bash_profile` but not `~/.bashrc`.

See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html:

> #### Invoked as an interactive login shell, or with --login
>
> When Bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists. After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable. The --noprofile option may be used when the shell is started to inhibit this behavior.

So either:

1. Use `~/.bash_profile` instead of `~/.bashrc`.
2. Use `~/.bashrc` but source `~/.bashrc` from `~/.bash_profile`.
3. Tell your terminal application to open new shells as non-login shells.

I have done the last two. For example `tmux` and the shell mode in Emacs open new shells as non-login shells. I still source `~/.bashrc` from `~/.bash_profile` because Bash is opened as a login shell when I ssh to my computer.

Answer (score 7):

If you are on Mac and you want to `source ~/.bash_profile` automatically on when a `terminal` is opened

1. Open **Terminal**
2. Go to **Preferences**
3. Go to **Profiles**
4. Select then open **shell**
5. Add this command  `source ~/.bash_profile` in Run command
   [image]

Answer (score 3):

If you want to source your bash_profile file everytime you open a new tab you can also set up a command on Iterm.

Go to Preferences -> Profiles -> General -> Command

[image: iter-bash-profile]

Answer (score 3):

I encounter the same problem and I solve it.
The macos have shift the default shell from `bash` to `zsh`.

So I try to modify the `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile` and `source` that but just work to current Terminal.

**The fact is you should modify the `~/.zshrc` profile file.**

Try it my friend!

Comment: I spent so much time looking for a solution but nobody mentioned that mac shifted to `~/.zshrc`. Top answer

Answer (score -1):

1. nano ~.bash_profile (Opens the ~.bash_profile)
2. aliasname(){
   ssh user@ipaddress
   }(You can add any command for the alias, I have shown the ssh command for a particular IP address)
3. Press Control+O and press Enter (Save the file). Control+X(Exit nano editor)
4. source .bash_profile

Now you have a persistent command across all the terminals whenever you type aliasname.