# My .bash_profile changes didnt take place even after restarting mac terminal, what can i do?

Tags: python, bash, macos

So basically I tried to make changes to my path in my .bash_profile and save the changes but whenever I restart my terminal, it changes back to the default path and not the one ive set in .bash_profile

Ive tried to use the source ~/.bash_profile command but which i thought helped but somehow, when i restart the terminal, it doesnt change to the settings ive placed in .bash_profile

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

alias python=python3
alias pip=pip3
```

The expected output is when i type python in mac os terminal
it should appear as python 3.7 and not python 2

Comment: Try sourceing your bashrc profile. Discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21211281/source-command-on-mac

Comment: Are you sure you are using `bash`? If this is a new account on macOS 10.15, you are probably using `zsh` instead.

Answer (score 15):

Put your commands into ~/.zshrc file on **macOS Catalina**

```
nano ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: Only solution that worked for me on macOS Catalina.

Comment: with this answer and using this link I setup xampp php on mac 
https://gist.github.com/djandyr/c04950a1375e96814316

Answer (score 10):

Starting with macOS Catalina, the default interactive shell is zsh:
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208050

Make sure that you are using bash as your login shell.
You can check what is your login shell with the command `echo $SHELL`. If the result is `/bin/bash`, then you are using bash as your login shell. Otherwise you can change it with the command `chsh -s /bin/bash`.

Comment: Got this after the Big Sur update 11.0.1, the default interactive shell is forced to zsh. Thats why my bash_profile changes weren't working, they kept resetting after restarting terminal. After issuing your fix, it finally worked. Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to do should be in `.bashrc` file, and not `.bash_profile`

also maybe your `.bashrc` file override those aliases

you can read more about the difference of them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment)

Comment: On macOS, a terminal window opens a login shell, not an ordinary interactive shell, since the terminal emulator itself isn't being started in an environment set up by a login shell.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that fixed this problem for me was changing the shell terminal preferences to open shell with command(complete path)

But thank you all for the replies greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Catalina, and here is what works for me
1.open with vim - **vi  .zprofile**
2.edit the content 
3.save the profile file -  **source .zprofile**