# Using ZSH for storing environment variable

Tags: command-line, environment-variables, zsh

It was suggested to me to utilize ZSH for storing environment variables for a project I'm working on. When I set them with `export VAR_NAME='secret_key'` on the command line it works, but does not persist beyond that shell session.

Reading around it sounds like I should be adding them in a `.zshenv` file. That file does not appear to exist for me. Not sure how where to create that file in my $PATH. Contrary to that approach I was told just to use my `.zshrc` file. Though when I add my env vars in there `export VAR_NAME='secret_key'` they are not picked up by my application like they were when I ran that syntax from the command line.

I'm kinda lost in what is the best approach for this, and how to get it done.

Couple resources I've been reading though:

http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide02.html

[Where to place $PATH variable assertions in zsh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574684/where-to-place-path-variable-assertions-in-zsh)

Comment: You appear to be completely confused about the very basic shell concepts. Read `man zsh` in full, especially the `STARTUP/SHUTDOWN FILES` section.

Answer (score 0):

Closed everything down and walked away for the day. Came back this morning and it just worked. C'est la vie. Not sure what it was as I killed the server a few times trying to figure it out, but it is working now. Still not sure if saving those env vars in the `.zshrc` file is best practice. Or if another location is more ideal.

Comment: Storing in ~/.zshenv is better approach, run "nano ~/.zshenv" add line: export PATH=$PATH:<folder>