# zsh: command not found: conda, when every new terminal opened

Tags: terminal, miniconda

on OSX, every new terminal opened, I need to re-do the:

```
export PATH=~/miniconda3/bin:$PATH
```

or it will be

```
zsh: command not found: conda
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This question is probably a duplicate (already answered), but you need to search something like `macosx zsh how to permanently add to path`. Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574684/where-to-place-path-variable-assertions-in-zsh  If it is a duplicate, it's best you delete this question, otherwise edit it to say that you have searched, and paste links to similar questions which do not cover what you asked or this question will probably get downvoted.

Answer (score 6):

Add
`export PATH=~/miniconda3/bin:$PATH`
to ~/.zshrc

Here is good explanation about startup files: http://superuser.com/questions/187639/zsh-not-hitting-profile

Comment: solved, thank you. can you explain why this happened?