# Add to PATH on server

Tags: terminal, path

i want to add the following directory to my path on the server, and i want it to stay permanently and be allowed to be run from anyplace
this is the directory path:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-linux
```

i tired the following but if i exit the server and login again it is not there and if a website tried to call a function from the directory it can not see it

```
PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH
```

what is the proper way to add this directory to my default $PATH and make this change permanent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the shell you are using on the server if `bash` you could edit your `.profile` and add something like:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH"
```

If you want it to be for all users you could add it to a file in `/etc/profile.d/path.sh`.

`/etc/profile` and `/etc/profile.d/*.sh` are the global initialization scripts that are equivalent to `~/.profile` for each user.

If using `zsh` add it to `~/.zshrc` check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10583324/1135424

If using `csh`, you could edit the `.cshrc` something like this:

```
set path = (/usr/local/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-linux $path)
```

Comment: I opened /etc/profile.d/ but did not find path.sh should i create one there? What my profile.d has are bash_completion.sh Z97-byobu.sh and Z99-cloud-locale-test.sh

Comment: Yes, you should create it, you could name it anything you want just needs to ends in `.sh`