# react-native run-android build failing because of error

Tags: android, react-native

Im new to react-native app development and I am running into the following problem upon running

```
JS server already running.
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat installDebug)...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using 
BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory().
> Could not create service of type PluginResolutionStrategyInternal using 
BuildScopeServices.createPluginResolutionStrategy().

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or -- 
debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Command failed: gradlew.bat installDebug

Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat installDebug
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:637:11)
at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:655:13)
at runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\daan-\OneDrive\SchoolProjects\EmojiDictRN\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\runAndroid\runAndroid.js:299:19)
at buildAndRun (C:\Users\daan-\OneDrive\SchoolProjects\EmojiDictRN\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\runAndroid\runAndroid.js:135:12)
at isPackagerRunning.then.result (C:\Users\daan-\OneDrive\SchoolProjects\EmojiDictRN\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\runAndroid\runAndroid.js:65:12)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:81:5)
```

I have installed and configured SDK and made the environment variables...

How can I fix this?

EDIT: cd'd into the android folder and ran gradlew.bat installDebug --stacktrace, got the following:

```
Exception is:
org.gradle.internal.service.ServiceCreationException: Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory().
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:816)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:767)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:571)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:628)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:780)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:766)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:571)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:628)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:780)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:766)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:571)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:628)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.find(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:295)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:284)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:279)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.doNewInstance(DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.java:179)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.newInstance(DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.java:108)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:40)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:61)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.service.ServiceCreationException: Could not create service of type PluginResolutionStrategyInternal using BuildScopeServices.createPluginResolutionStrategy().
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:816)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:767)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:571)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:628)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:780)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:766)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:571)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:628)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.find(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:295)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:284)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:279)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.scopes.BuildScopeServices.defaultScriptPluginFactory(BuildScopeServices.java:301)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.scopes.BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory(BuildScopeServices.java:293)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.invoke(ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:814)
        ... 61 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not generate a proxy class for class org.gradle.plugin.management.internal.DefaultPluginResolutionStrategy.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractClassGenerator.generateUnderLock(AbstractClassGenerator.java:228)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.ClassGeneratorBackedInstantiator.newInstance(ClassGeneratorBackedInstantiator.java:36)
        at org.gradle.plugin.internal.PluginUsePluginServiceRegistry$BuildScopeServices.createPluginResolutionStrategy(PluginUsePluginServiceRegistry.java:106)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.invoke(ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:814)
        ... 79 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(Ljava/lang/String;[BIILjava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/security/ProtectionDomain;)Ljava/lang/Class;
        at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.define(ClassLoaderUtils.java:104)
        at org.gradle.model.internal.asm.AsmClassGenerator.define(AsmClassGenerator.java:58)
        at org.gradle.model.internal.asm.AsmClassGenerator.define(AsmClassGenerator.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AsmBackedClassGenerator$ClassBuilderImpl.generate(AsmBackedClassGenerator.java:967)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractClassGenerator.generateUnderLock(AbstractClassGenerator.java:226)
        ... 88 more
```

Comment: Can you try running `gradlew.bat installDebug --stacktrace` from the command line?

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, it says: 'gradlew.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Did I forget to install something or add an environment variable?

Comment: Uhm, I'm assuming you're using Android Studio. Is there a gradle directory or similar there with a gradlew.bat?

Comment: And also make sure you're in the project directory from the command line

Comment: Yes, when I open the android folderin the project, there is a gradlew.bat file

Comment: Ah, then `cd` into the android folder and execute the command there and post the output

Comment: Alright, this is what I got a lot of lines, is there a different way to post it here? The lines are 13000 characters too long :)

Comment: Put it into the post as an edit ;)

Comment: I literally just ran into this issue. Any updates here? Seems like it might be a java version issue..

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that your `$JAVA_HOME` is not pointing to the right java version. **Android only works with Java 8!**

Fix this:

1. Install the right version of Java using brew:

```
brew tap caskroom/versions
brew cask install java8
```

2. Update your `.bash_profile` or [.zsh profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574684/where-to-place-path-variable-assertions-in-zsh) to include this

```
Export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`
```

3. Now run `react-native run-android` from your `dir/to/MyAwesomeProject` and it should work!

---

**If the above answer doesn't work for you, you can use this work around.**

Run dev server manually and build manually from Android Studio:

1. Go to `dir/to/MyAwesomeProject` and run `react-native start`. This starts the development server.
2. Launch **Android Studio**, click *"Open an existing Android Studio project"* and select the `dir/to/MyAwesomeProject/android`
3. Make sure you have [Android emulator or device connected](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started#preparing-the-android-device).
4. In **Android Studio** click the Play button. A dialog box should appear with list of "Connected Devices". Your emulator or device should appear there. Double click the one you want to build on and it should build on that device.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I solved that issue putting it on build.gradle, before allprojects method.

```
subprojects {   project.configurations.all {
     resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
        if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
              && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
           details.useVersion "28.0.0"
        }
     }   } }
```

I also changed the react native version to "react-native": "0.57.3", on package.json.

After that, you just build and run...